# Map apache path to different machines, which is the best way?

Tags: apache

I am new with apache and i dont know which is the best way to do what i want.

I have an apache installed on a linux machine and is listening to a domain name lets say service.example.com this is a public internet domain name, this apache is exposed to the internet. I tunnel traffic into my private network from the apache. Inside my private network i have 2 application servers hosting web services. What i want to accomplish is, if somebody is trying to access a web service in service.example.com/webservice to be mapped to application server#1 and if somebody tries to access service.example.com/test/webservice to be mapped to application server#2. As you all have understood we are talking about the same  application servers with the same webservices... the only difference is that the one is used for testing and the other one is the real deal.

Which is the best way to do this ???

A friend told me why not use virtual hosts... But as far as i understand the concept i dont have another IP nor a different domain name.

Any suggestions???

Thanks

Comment: I would honestly take you friend's advice and set up your test environment on its own domain/subdomain.  That way you can do routing at the DNS level, and your application URI's would be able to be identical (none of that `/test/...` stuff).

Comment: Thx Mike for your answer. When i read what virtual hosts were, i thought it is the best thing. But as i said i only have one public domain name.. Is this possible to be done with only one ??

Comment: Yes,  You register the domain which is just like `example.com`.  You can make as many subdomains (i.e. `www`, `test`, etc.) on that domain as you want. You can have virtual hosts or totally separate servers (which it sounds like you want) with DNS-level routing.  Just whatever makes sense for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this routing using [mod_proxy module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) of Apache.

Something like this:

```
ProxyPass /webservice http://server1/webservice
ProxyPass /test/webservice http://server2/webservice
```

Comment: Thx Anubhava , I will have to study that that module is and how to use it in my case.. and i will get back to you if i have any problems